# The decomposition of inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If $V$,$W$are two inner product spaces and $L:V\to W$ is a linear map with its adjoint $L^\star$, then is there a decomposition of $W$=ker$(L^\star)$ $ \oplus $ im$(L)$ ? (It is easy that the conclusion holds if $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional)

Comment: What if $\operatorname{im}{L}$ isn't closed?

Comment: Which duals do you consider? Algebraic or continuous?

Comment: @Norbert algebraic, since we do not assume that $L$ is continuous.

Comment: @t.b. I see. If the decomposition does exist, then im($L$) should be closed. But what if we assume first that im($L$) is closed?

Comment: I think, $L^*$ is not well definied, so you should give your definition.